# Error installing Wine 1.7

Tags: wine

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.7

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: binfmt-support (>= 1.1.2) but it is not installable
           Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.18-0ubuntu1~saucy1)
           Recommends: fonts-droid but it is not installable
           Recommends: fonts-horai-umefont but it is not installable
           Recommends: fonts-unfonts-core but it is not installable
           Recommends: winbind but it is not installable
           Recommends: winetricks but it is not going to be installed
N: Ignoring file 'medibuntu.list.broken' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How to fix this errors?

**output of `apt-cache policy wine1.7 binfmt-support wine1.7-i386`**

```
wine1.7:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.7.18-0ubuntu1~saucy1
  Version table:
     1:1.7.18-0ubuntu1~saucy1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
binfmt-support:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
wine1.7-i386:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.7.18-0ubuntu1~saucy1
  Version table:
     1:1.7.18-0ubuntu1~saucy1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ saucy/main i386 Packages
N: Ignoring file 'medibuntu.list.broken' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'medibuntu.list.broken' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

**output of `sudo apt-get install binfmt-support wine1.7-i386`**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package binfmt-support is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

N: Ignoring file 'medibuntu.list.broken' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'medibuntu.list.broken' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Package 'binfmt-support' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy wine1.7 binfmt-support wine1.7-i386` and the output of `sudo apt-get install binfmt-support wine1.7-i386`

Comment: And why is there an entry `saucy1` in your error message? What's your Ubuntu version, add thje output of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Sorry, that's Ubuntu 13.10 and that's a EOL release. Therefore off-topic. :\

Comment: @A.B. It is 13.10. Should I upgrade it to current version?

Comment: Yes, in any case.

Comment: @A.B. Do you think it will resolve the problem?